# Connection error when trying to connect to ElasticSearch in Python, but able to connect via Postman using same credentials

Tags: python, elasticsearch, postman, openai-api

I am able to query ES in Postman using the URI of the clean index and Bearer token. I have the following code to test querying from Python:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
...
token = response['access_token']
url = 'https://cleanindex.staging.xyz.com/' 
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{'host': url, 'port': 9200, 'scheme':'https'}],
    basic_auth=('bearer_auth', token),
    request_timeout=10,
    verify_certs=False
)
```

When I try to perform querying test, I get a connection error:

```
# Perform a query
index = 'staging_index/_search'
query = {
    'query': {
        'match': {
            'field_name': 'search_term',
        },
    }
}
try:
    results = es.search(index=index, body=query,timeout=5)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

> Connection error caused by: ConnectionError(Connection error caused
> by: NameResolutionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x000002102BCD4A60>: Failed to resolve
> 'https://cleanindex.staging.xyz.com/' ([Errno 11001]
> getaddrinfo failed)))

How do I resolve this error?

Additional error:

[image: Please see additional Error found upon trying to connect]

Comment: NameResolutionError Failed to resolve... there is an issue with your domain name `cleanindex.staging.xyz.com`, it's not related to our credentials

Comment: it is the same URI that we use in the Postman query. We are able to connect. Any ideas why it's not connecting in Python? Or any missing arguments that I need to add?

Comment: I have tried that but I get the same exact error.

Comment: What version of the client library and ES do you have?

Comment: ES: version 8.10.1

Comment: Can you try as [described in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/getting-started-python.html#_connecting), i.e. not specifying the `hosts` parameter but simply the full URL as the first parameter

Comment: This method seem to resolve the connection error. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You should do it [as described in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/python-api/current/getting-started-python.html#_connecting), by not specifying the `hosts` parameter but simply the full URL as the first parameter :

```
token = response['access_token']
url = 'https://cleanindex.staging.xyz.com:9200/'
es = Elasticsearch(
    url,
    bearer_auth=token,
    request_timeout=10,
    verify_certs=False
)
```

Comment: I tried this method and it seems to resolve the connection error. However, I am now getting  a new error upon `client.info()`. Error is: ApiError: ApiError(302, "{'Message': 'Authorization has been denied for this request.'}"). Do you have any idea how to resolve this? The only parameters in Postman that we use is the token and url. It seems like it is redirecting to microsoft homepage.

Comment: your client variable is called `es` not `client`, do you get the same error when calling `es.info()` ?

Comment: yes, in my test code it's client not es, i forgot to change the variable name here. I am getting that error upon `es.info()` in this case. I use `requests` library for now as workaround but what might be the solution in this case?

Comment: Can you simply try `bearer_auth=token` instead of `basic_auth=('bearer_auth', token),` ?

Comment: yes I have tried that as well. `client = Elasticsearch( url, bearer_auth=token,request_timeout=10, verify_certs=False)` but the same error occurs.

Comment: Are you sure the token is valid? How are you getting it?

Comment: Yes token is valid. When I use `request`  I am able to connect. Do I need to install ElasticSearch in my machine? Please see the additional error part on the post for the full error.

Comment: It's a different error. The first one was `Failed to resolve https://cleanindex.staging.xyz.com` and the second one is a 302 stating that you are not authorized